# How to deploy smart contract that is exceeding max code size?

Tags: smartcontracts, hardhat

```
npx hardhat compile
npx hardhat run --network testnet scripts/deploy.js
```

error message

```
ProviderError: max code size exceeded
```

It has multiple contracts and used hardhat to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Optimize the code - allocate repeated code fragments into internal routines and so on.
2. Divide the code into several smart contracts that call each other's functionality.